# How to stop posgresql server using pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to stop postgres server 13 since I installed postgres 15. I look for a stop server button in pgadmin but it looks like that this kind of a button does not exist.

For such a simple functionality, I may have missed something. What do I think wrong? Why isn't there a stop server button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgAdmin is, contrary to what its name suggests, not a database administration program. It is a client program that offers a schema browser, an interactive query tool and support for import and export via `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`.

To [stop the server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-shutdown.html), you must log into the database server machine.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin is not intended to stop PostgreSQL servers. It's such a simple feature that you just need to use mechanism of your OS for that: systemctl or whatever on Linux, services.msc on Windows, don't know what on MacOS.